# Adding a fixed number of unique items to an array using a for loop and indexOf

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, indexof

I'm using a `for` loop to get 6 random numbers between 1-20, using `indexOf` to omit duplicates, and pushing them to an array.

However, I always want 6 items in the array, so I'd like duplicates to be replaced. In my naive code duplicates are simply omitted, which means that sometimes I'll get less than 6 in the array. How do I replace the omissions to fill those 6 array slots?

```
function rolld(event:MouseEvent) {
    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++){
        d = (Math.floor(Math.random() * (1 + d_hi - d_lo)) + d_lo);
        if (rollArray.indexOf(d) < 0){
            rollArray.push(d);
        }
    }
    trace (rollArray);
}
```

Still very new to this. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

When you get an element from array with 20 elements, try to remove it from array.

```
function rolld(event:MouseEvent) {

    var elements:Array = [];

    for (var i:int = 1; i <= 20; i++)
    {
        elements.push(i);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++){

       d = (Math.floor(Math.random() * elements.length);

       rollArray.push(d);

       //remove the element
       elements.splice(d, 1);
    }

    trace (rollArray);
}
```

Comment: If I use splice, there's no need to use indexOf as well, right? My main issue is getting a new random number generated for any that have been omitted or spliced. Thanks

Comment: I don't see any difference between generate 6 different number in one time and generate them in some times.And if you use splice, you don't need to check if duplicatenumber existed.

Comment: ok so the answer is yes? If I use splice, there's no need to use indexOf? Both works fine for me; the real problem is how to replace duplicates with a new number, so there are always 6 output. Thanks for your answer, but right now I need to learn how to replace duplicates with a new number.